# Unable to run even basic example with TF 2.0 and GPU support in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow

A newer version of TF (v2.0) is migrating towards XLA devices, however this causes TF to loose such devices. The basic example Colab (can be found here) https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb#scrollTo=v3fE7KmKRDsH) does not seem to work even with GPU turned on in the environment options tab. The problem persists, the model is being run on either CPU or when explicitly specified through the use of `with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0'):`:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'): # <=== Device not found
  ...

with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0'): # <=== This part runs fine but in attempt to run inference or training fails with exception (see below)
  base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                           include_top=False, 
                                           weights='imagenet') 

  maxpool_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()
  prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      base_model,
      maxpool_layer,
      prediction_layer
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.summary()
```

However the following line of code fails with exception:

```
with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0'):
  history = model.fit(train_data.repeat(),
                      epochs=num_epochs,
                      steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch)
```

Sorry didn't record the exception cuz it would take around an hour to spin-up my colab once again (and it's 5 am here), the problem however seems abundant there seems no way to use GPU provided by Colab with TF 2.0.

Here is the link to my colab, it's a simple thumbs-up detector

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ycfeET5DeqpI3oaY1gt5PpalqPNmqECg

(Unable to provide you with dataset, it's big, sorry... Also sorry for the quality of code, it was not supposed to be viewed by anyone but me...)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that CUDA 10.1 was installed recently at Google Colab, and the newest stable compilation of TensorFlow 2 does not support CUDA 10.1. The workaround is to use nightly preview of Tensorflow 2, so use:

```
pip install tf-nightly-gpu
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/864#issuecomment-556437040). It is a bug from Tensorflow.

Just insert this line at the top of your notebook and restart kernel.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```